# Java algorithm query

Tags: java, math

I'm wanting to find the average difference of the array totals.

My array structures are as follows (pulled from a database):

`day`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`

So you can see the 5 arrays how it's pulled from the database.

Now for instance, the Java algorithm I need is as follows:

To add each of the 1,2,3,4 values up, then loop to the next day (if there is one), repeating the same addition. Then eventually, calculate the 'average difference' between the totals of each day.

So for example, i've done some sample data to try and make it clearer for you!

```
1 (Mon)     135 90  105 150
2 (Tues)    143 86  117 163
3 (Wed)     129 100 140 158
```

So what the algorithm needs to do is:

135+90+105+150 = 500,

143+86+117+163 = 509,

129+100+140+158 = 527

But the only problem, is that, column 1 is its own array and column 2,3,4 preceding.

Calculate the 'average increase/decrease' which would be:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16554/what-is-average-increase-percentage-and-how-to-calculate-it

I'm unsure how to implement it into Java! Any help would be appreciated.

If i can provide any more information please let me know.

Many thanks.

Comment: Which part of this, specifically, are you having trouble with?

Comment: The entire algorithm, i've tried for loops through the day array, using the 'pointer' to associate with 1,2,3,4 but to no success. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you've got so far, and how it doesn't work.

Comment: The for loop I previously created doesn't do anything related as to what I want it to do, I can still post if necessary?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the column-based arrays into row-based, or how to get just the rows from the database?  If it's the latter, we'll need more information about the database.

Comment: Column based into Row based would be a good start as I need the totals of each of the row to then calculate the difference. 

The rows are already been passed into my application, but in column format as i'm using JSON to gather them from the database.

Comment: @BenLittle: I guess what I'm getting at is that your question is too broad at the moment.  No-one is going to provide you a complete solution, so your best bet is to focus on the one specific issue that's preventing you from progressing, and to ask a question about that.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to calculate. What exactly is "the average difference of the array totals"? Is it the average daily percent change of the sum of numbers?

Comment: Yes it's exactly that @TedHopp, the average daily percent change of the sum of numbers. How ever, with each array been in column not row format, this is where i'm struggling.

Comment: The question could be clearer, sure. But why the down-vote? Just ask the OP to clarify any information you're missing, and as you can see above, he has.

Comment: @Hassan - I'm not the down-voter, but I can see why someone voted it. A down-vote can be "earned" because a question is unclear, which this certainly was. In my opinion, it's still unclear just what OP needs help with. (Summing the daily values? Computing the percentage?) If OP clarifies, the down-voter can always remove the down-vote.

Comment: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." I don't think this post qualifies.

Comment: @Hassan - I don't know where that quote came from. I prefer to use the discussion on meta [Proper reasons to downvote a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54914/proper-reasons-to-downvote-a-question) Also, if you hover over the downvote arrow, it gives a different criterion: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

Comment: @TedHopp It's from the privileges page: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down. I'm not really trying to make a big deal out of this, it just bugs me when people down-vote at the drop of a hat. I followed your link though, and read some of it, and I still don't think this post was bad enough to warrant a down-vote.

Comment: @Hassan - Well, I kind of agree with you. I left a comment, but didn't downvote. I just see how someone could reasonably come to a different conclusion, is all.

Comment: @TedHopp Okay, well I suppose you reasonably could. At any rate, I don't think this is the place to discuss. Maybe I'll ask on meta someday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we know the location of the items in the database, the following might work:

```
/*Psudeocode:
ArrayList<Integer> firstCol = //get first column
ArrayList<Integer> secondCol = //get second column
....
ArrayList<Integer> nCol = //get n column
*/
ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int currentRow;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
     currentRow = 0;
     currentRow += firstCol.get(i);
     currentRow += secondCol.get(i);
     //etc, etc...
     values.add(currentRow);
}
//At this point, values contains all the sums of the different rows.
//To calculate the average percent change:
//PR= (((Vpresent - Vpast) / Vpast) x 100) / N
for(int i=0;i<values.size() -1;i++)
{
    System.out.println(((values.get(i+1) - values.get(i)) * 100) / (i+1))
}
```

I hope this helps.  [Help with Average Percent Change](http://www.ehow.com/how_5485263_calculate-average-percent-change.html)

Comment: Hi @SomeKittens, many thanks for your response. This now prints out the data within 1 array side by side correctly. I can see where you are going with this. 

Within the section 'Average Increase Percentage here' could you perhaps shed some light on how I can find the average difference of each of the 4 values.

Comment: I've added the formula, as well as Java implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Have you arrived at this stage first of all to be able to access all the elements? (if I understood your question correctly?)

```
//first for loop loops through the number of days
for (int i = 0; i < day.length; i++)
{   //second for loop loops through all integers in Ith day
    for (int j = 0; j < day[i].length; j++)
    {
        print day[i][j] 
    }
}
```